# Update PHP prepare bindparam

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $UpdateChecklist = 'UPDATE checklists SET ADMIN_ID=?, COMPUTER_ID=? WHERE id=?';
        $stmtChecklist = $connection->prepare($UpdateChecklist);
        $stmtChecklist->bind_param('ii', $_POST['ADMIN_ID'], $_POST['COMPUTER_ID']);

        $isUpdate = $stmtChecklist->execute();
        $lastUpdateId = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

        $stmtChecklist->close();

        $UpdateInstalledProgram = 'UPDATE checklist_programs SET CHECKLIST_ID=?, PROGRAM_ID=? WHERE id = ?';
        $stmtProgramId = $connection->prepare($UpdateInstalledProgram);
        $stmtProgramId->bind_param('ii', $lastUpdateId, $programId);
        foreach ($_POST['PROGRAM_ID'] as $program) {
            $programId = $program;
            $stmtProgramId->execute();
        }
        $connection->close();
        if ($isUpdate) {
            header('Location: OverViewCheckList.php');
            exit(0);
        }
    }
?>
```

and, I got some error which I don't know how to fix it:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklist\updateChecklist.php on line 34
>
> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklist\updateChecklist.php on line 44
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklist\updateChecklist.php on line 57
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklist\updateChecklist.php on line 59

Comment: You're requiring (3) values in your update query but you only have (2) items in your `bind_param`.

Answer (score 3):

In your both of your queries you are using 3 ?'s but only binding 2 variables.

Query 1:

```
$UpdateChecklist = 'UPDATE checklists SET ADMIN_ID=?, COMPUTER_ID=? WHERE id=?';
$stmtChecklist = $connection->prepare($UpdateChecklist);

$stmtChecklist->bind_param('ii', $_POST['ADMIN_ID'], $_POST['COMPUTER_ID']); /* Here*/
```

Query 2:

```
$UpdateInstalledProgram = 'UPDATE checklist_programs
SET CHECKLIST_ID=?, PROGRAM_ID=? WHERE id = ?';
$stmtProgramId = $connection->prepare($UpdateInstalledProgram);

$stmtProgramId->bind_param('ii', $lastUpdateId, $programId); /* Here */
```

You need to add a third variable e.g.:

```
$stmtChecklist->bind_param('iii', $_POST['ADMIN_ID'], $_POST['COMPUTER_ID'], $id3);
$stmtProgramId->bind_param('iii', $lastUpdateId, $programId, $id3);
```

Comment: @CherryDT he has 3 ?'s so you need 3 binds e.g. `$stmtProgramId->bind_param('iii', $lastUpdateId, $programId, $id3)` ii is only 2 bindings

Comment: right, I was confused for a sec. nvm. this is the right answer (and probably also for the first query).

Comment: That's the problem in both queries.

Comment: @clemens321 thats my sleepyness there. I thought he only had 2 ?'s. Thank you